# Is it possible to run a script with ssh2shell or simple-ssh using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, telnet

In a previous question, I asked if it was possible to run a telnet session from a remote SSH session using node.js. I usually connect to a linux server via an SSH putty session, and then telnet to another idirect / modem. I would like to do this programmatically using node.js. From the answer received, I understand that I must run an expect script to execute the required telnet commands.

Is it possible to run a script using `ssh2shell` or `simple-ssh`?

Answer (score 0):

It is totally doable, from what I understand in your question is that you want to connect via SSH to a server, and then run a script? Please elaborate a little bit.

There are some tools to run shell commands via Node.js :
 - [ShellJS](http://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs) 
 - [Exec-sh](https://github.com/tsertkov/exec-sh#readme)

One thing to note is that those tools you have to port your script to their syntax, but they are still shell commands, they offer error handling too.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply.
Via `ssh2shell` , i can SSH into a remote machine. From this remote machine, i need to telnet to another router / modem. I only have knowledge of running individual commands  with `ssh2shell'.  I need to run an expect script in order to login and execute commands in the telnet session.

So, i need to remote to a machine via SSH and then telnet from that machine to another router.

The main problem is i need to run a local script from my machine on the remote machine.

Comment: And in this layout where do you want to sit your app? Right in the first machine that connects via SSH?

Comment: The app needs to sit in the first machine  > connects to second machine via ssh > connects to third machine via telnet

Comment: What im thinking on top of my head is that you can make a local SSH tunel from the linux server to the telnet modem, this way, you only make commands on the first machine(app) and it "appears" as if you are only doing one connection.

So this way 

app that sends telnet commands via ssh > machine running linux with local SSH tunnel > machine via telnet.
This will help you understanding tunnels
[Send Telnet command inside a SSH Tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/696141/send-telnet-command-inside-a-ssh-tunnel)

Comment: [SSH tunnels](https://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information. It's clear. Just not sure how i can achieve this via node.js.  I do see tunnelling options with 'ssh2shell'. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: It's just the implementation you decide because at the end of the day you will only run commands in your Node.js app if setting up the tunnels properly.

Answer (score 0):

I used node-ssh.

You can connect to the instance, and you can use it like this:

```
let sshConnection = ssh.connect({
    host: <host>,
    username: <username>,
    privateKey: '/path/to/id-rsa'
  })

  sshConnection.then(() => {
    ssh.putFile('./script.py', '/tmp/script.py').then(() => {
      log('The File thing is done')
    }, (error) => {
      log('Somethings wrong', error)
    })
  })

  sshConnection.then(() => {
    ssh.execCommand(`echo hello-world`, { cwd: '/home' })
    .then((result) => {
      log(`result.stdout = ${result.stdout}`)
      log(`result.stderr = ${result.stderr}`)
    })
  })
```

Comment: Hi. My main issue is the second telnet server. I can connect via SSH using node.js  to the first linux server but cannot execute an expect script to connect from linux server via telnet to the second router. 

I think the option to use an SSH tunnel might be what i should be going for.